# Unexpected Statement Function at 1 in Fortran

Tags: fortran, fortran77

I am new to Fortran and writing this small program to write out 100 ordered pairs for a circle.

But I get the error mentioned above and I don't know how to resolve.

```
  implicit real*8(a-h,o-z)
  parameter(N=100)
  parameter(pi = 3.14159265358979d0)
  integer*8 k


  dtheta=2*pi/N
  r=1.0d0
  x00=0.0d0
  y00=0.0d0
  do k=0,N-1
   xb(k)=r*cos(k*dtheta)-x00
   yb(k)=r*sin(k*dtheta)-y00
  enddo

  open(64,file='xbyb.m',status='unknown')
  write(64,*) (xb(k),k=0,N-1),(yb(k),k=0,N-1)

  close(64)
  end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not declare the arrays `xb` and `yb`.

Although not technically FORTRAN 77 I still suggest using `implicit none` or at least an equivalent compiler option to be forced to declare everything explicitly. Implicit typing is evil and leads to bugs.

As High Performance Mark reminds, the syntax

```
  f(k) = something
```

declares a feature (now obsolescent in Fortran 95 and later) called a statement function. It declares a function of one argument `k`. The only way for the compiler to recognize you mean an array reference instead is to properly declare the array. The compiler complains the statement function is unexpected because the declaration must be placed before the executable statements.

Your implied do loop in the `write` statement is Fortran 90 anyway, so no need to stick to FORTRAN 77 in the 21st century.

Other tips:
  `status='unknown'` is redundant, that is the default, just leave it out.
  You can just write `r = 1` and `x00 = 0`.

Comment: Sorry, I find FORTRAN and this issue morbidly interesting... I think I get that the compiler struggled to understand the xb and yb references as arrays and thought they might be an ancient feature called a "STATEMENT FUNCTION" .... the one remaining mystery in the error message though: "Why was the STATEMENT FUNCTION at 1" unexpected? I mean it clearly isn't line #1?

Comment: @Travis A statement function cannot appear there. It must be placed right after the type and variable declarations. BTW, it has been called Fortran, not FORTRAN, for almost 30 years.

Comment: My observation was not about the subject of the error message but the location. The message itself is at best obscure about where the problem was encountered. "STATEMENT FUNCTION at 1 unexpected"? What does 'at 1' mean and why does the compiler think it has encountered this problem 'at 1'? For such an analytical type language as FORTRAN, or Fortran if you insist, I suppose I expected it to be more accurate or at least more specific about the problems it encountered.

Comment: @Travis that is how all gfortran, or perhaps even all GCC, error messages work. There a line quoted in the error message and under that is number 1 which marks the specific column in that line. It is literally "at 1" **not** "at line 1"